# Wrap hyperlink to existing text in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, hyperlink

I am attempting to add a hyperlink to the existing string in column "ID". How do you wrap the hyperlinks to the ID#?

##### Import Modules

import pandas as pd

#### DataFrame

df1 = pd.read_excel('D:\List.xlsx')

#### Add Hyperlink to the beginning and end of column "url"

df1['url'] = 'https://stackoverflow/' + df1['ID'].astype(str)  #Insert "https://stackoverflow/"

df1['url'] = df1['url'].astype(str) + '.com'                   #Insert ".com"

```
 ID                 url
```

0   6685    https://stackoverflow/6685.com
1   3341    https://stackoverflow/3341.com

The expected result is to have the "ID" clickable without the associated url visible:

new-url
0   6685
1   3341

Comment: Are the end results writing to excel? Or are you using Jupyter notebook or some other enviroment?

Comment: If you are writing to excel, you could use xlsx writer but you would need to iterate through the column to add a hyperlink for each link. Here are the docs https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_hyperlink.html

Comment: I don't believe you are able to import an existing document using xlsxwriter, which means i will be unable to append the existing dataframe